# Any suggestion other than Solr n-gram

Tags: solr, n-gram

I'm using solr 3.5, but I have encountered a problem.
Which I want to do is to compare each line in file1 with the reference listed in file2. But in file1, the data is not necessarily write correctly. So I decide to use nGram to cut the words by letters from 3 to 15.
The problem is when I cut the words by 3, there are too many references match; but if cut by 15, there will be no match :(
Anyone who have an idea to solve this problem ?

Thank you!
Bo

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the spellcheck component. Use the file2's field as the dictionary.
see the tutorial http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent

Comment: Thank u! But i didn't found any good example about it. And the explanation is a litte difficult to put into practice!